# ImportError: No module named detector_classifier

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm working with Concept Drift, but when trying to run my code i get this error
"ImportError: No module named detector_classifier" been trying to install the module with pip install, but all i get is no match found. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can import third party libraries, you need to install first. If you could not install with pip install, it means it's not published on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). You need to install directly from source where you found code/module for Concept Drift or detector_classifier, or whatever you're trying to use.

Comment: I simply cloned this git repo: https://github.com/SmileYuhao/ConceptDrift  and tried to run the test.py

Comment: following what you said and it seems to work, but i get an error in the setup.py:  File "./setup.py", line 20
    setup(**config, requires=['numpy'])
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: oh that's because the guy who wrote this made a mistake on his setup.py it seems like. You should just clone his repo and add to your python path then to import his code. Or you can edit his setup.py and set it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think a little more information might help. Which python version and which pip version are you using? I just googled "detector_classifier" and couldn't find anything. What library does "detector_classifier" belong to?

Without much background to go off of, I would recommended making sure you have updated pip. Depending on what operating system you're using, your configuration might need some tinkering so your system knows where to look.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer

Comment: I simply cloned this git repo https://github.com/SmileYuhao/ConceptDrift  and was trying to run the test.py file when doing so i get error on line 8 saying ImportError: No module named detector_classifier. Im running ubuntu 18.04, using pip-18.0